# Play Framework 2 command line task

Tags: command-line, playframework-2.0, pipe

Is it possible to define a command line task in Play Framework 2? 
The reason I'm asking is because I need an executable that will generate XML from my Play project to the stdout. There is an external application - that I do not control - that will execute it and pipe it's output in order to process the XML. Right now, to get the job done, I just write the XML in an action and fetch it with "wget -qO- http://...." but this is far from ideal. Also I need to be able to deploy this into production as well.

I searched for solutions extensively, but came empty handed.

Comment: So the external app is a command line tool that you will start once and that will run as long as your play app is alive?

Comment: No, not really. To make it clearer is about the [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) indexer. In it's configuration you point the indexer to an executable that produces XML to the stdout. When you run the indexer it launches that executable and pipes it's output in order to index the XML.

Comment: In this particular situation the Play command line task would simply go through a Mongo collection, do some processing and write XML to the stdout. That's all I need it to do, but I just could not find any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think making an executable jar from the play project is ideal. Whatever logic you need to create your xml should be put into its own library that can then be reused.

Your play app can then depend on this library, and you can also create a new project that allows you to create an executable jar (which will also depend on the library).

Eg:

```
xml-generator-lib

play-app => dependsOn xml-generator-lib

my-executable-jar => dependsOn xml-generator-lib
```

That said, here's a trivial play app from which you can create an executable jar: https://github.com/edeustace/executable-play-app.

Its using the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to gather up all the jars into one. It also overrides the 'main' class to point to a class that renders one of the templates. It's also needs to manage overlapping files in the assembled jar.

I'd suspect that parts of the play framework may not function running in this context (without a server etc).